# What are light node's role in Casper?

Tags: nodes, light-clients, casper

So casper testnet is out and I have a few questions! 
From [previous discussions](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/4163/are-light-nodes-possible-in-casper) it seems that light nodes cannot be validators.

1. If this is correct, then what will the purpose of light nodes be as part of the ethereum network?
2. Will everyone who wants to participate need to run a full node in order to stake?
3. If I am mistaken and light nodes CAN participate in PoS and validate transactions, will the reward be a percentage of what a full node would get?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Lights nodes don't really serve the network a purpose, they just access the network through full nodes that have lightserve enabled (they allow light nodes to request information from them). Think of a light node as being what you have on your phone to trustlessly use the network without having to download the full blockchain.
2. Casper will require a full node, yes, unless you join a staking pool.
3. Light nodes can't really participate in PoS.

Comment: Would you mind clarifying exactly what you mean by Casper's *full node* requirement? Fast? Archive? +fat and/or +trace?